# Access denied for getting publicly available S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I created a bucket, where I allow objects to be publicly accessible.
I put a file in that bucket, and I can access it through a simple HTTP GET request (even from an anonymous browser).
However, trying to access the same file using the AWS SDK for .net's GetObject function (or even using AWS CLI) I get an access denied error.
What could I be doing wrong?

```
Private region As RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1

Public Function ReadObject(ByVal bucket As String, ByVal key As String) As String
  Dim request As New GetObjectRequest()
  request.BucketName = bucket
  request.Key = key
  Dim responseBody As String
  Dim client As New AmazonS3Client(region)
  Using response As GetObjectResponse = client.GetObject(request)
    Using responseStream As Stream = response.ResponseStream
      Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
        responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd()
      End Using
    End Using
  End Using
  Return responseBody
End Function
```

Comment: Either that user has a `Deny` policy that is overriding the public `Allow`, or your code is not actually retrieving that object (eg might be the wrong name). Can you provide some code for us to check?

Comment: Added the code to the original post. I can see the file in the S3 console when logged in with the same user, so it doesn't look like the user is denied.

Comment: Using SDK or CLI require AWS credentials. Are you sure credentials are set up correctly? Can you share error message?

Comment: Oh! If you can't access it via the CLI, then you have a credentials problem. Run `aws configure` and enter the Access Key & Secret Key associated with your IAM User.

Comment: I did run aws configure and entered my access and secret keys. I even create new credentials and used them, with the same result. 
This is the error I get:
     An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

Comment: If I run the CLI command with --debug, it prints the URL and headers being used. If I take these same URL and parameters into an HTTP client and send them, I get the file.